# Collapsing toolbar anchored view is hidding when collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to display a TextView (The circular shape with "0") anchored to the toolbar, like a FAB, but it must be ALWAYS VISIBLE.

My problem is that when I collapse the toolbar (scrolling the recyclerView), at the fully collapsed state, it hides the half of the view...
The TextView layout has this properties:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

[image: Expanded]

[image: Collapsed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your TextView be over the toolbar, in this case, you can try to set higher elevation value to TextView. In some cases, it worked for me.

For example:

```
android:elevation="15dp"
```

Comment: Wow! That works, but elevation is for API>21, would it have any compatibility problems?

Comment: @Borja I have tested a similar case on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini device with API 16 an worked well. I think elevation only have shadow issues for API>21. But I recommend to test this for yourself.

Comment: I have tested it and it works with different API versions, I think elevation is omitted in API<21. And if not, we can use layout-v21 folder to use different layouts depending on API version. Thanks!